# Fetching data from Oracle database does not work first time

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

We are trying to fetch data from Oracle DB using a PreparedStatement. It keeps fetching zero records while the same runs and fetches data when run from PL/SQL developer.

We found the root cause while trying to debug. While debugging the code fetched the two records properly.

We did a temporary fix by placing this piece of code.

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(!rs.hasNext()){
       ps.executeQuery();}
```

This works. But this is not the best solution since it results in an unwanted DB hit.It clearly looks like a time issue. We also explicitly committed earlier transactions since they can affect the result of this query.

What could be causing this. What's the best way to solve this?

The method is quite big: I'll just post some parts here:

```
 private static boolean loadCommission(Member member){
        Connection conn = getConnection("schema1");    //obtained through connection pool
        //insertion into table
        conn.close();
        Conn conn2 = getConnection("schema2");    //obtained through connection pool
        PreparedStatement ps = conn2.prepareStatement(sql); 
         //this sql combines data from schema1                           
        // and 2 with DB links 
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         //business logic
         conn2.close();
        return true;
       }
```

Thanks

We tried a few more things yesterday. We replaced the second connection code with direct jdbc connection like so

```
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

This too works. Now we are not sure if the delay is in getting connection from pool or in completing previous transaction like we thought earlier.

Comment: Can you share your complete code without the temporary fix

Answer (score 0):

If your query selects from a materialized view, then there may be some elapsed time before it will yield results (as materialized views do not necessarily refresh instantly after a commit, depending upon how they've been created).

If this is the case, then you can resolve the problem by either selecting directly from the base table (or equivalent non-materialized views), or forcing the materialized view to refresh.

Comment: There are no materialized views here.